# how to animate gltf model using three.js

Tags: three.js, gltf

I am trying to animate my 3d model, which is a gltf model. I am trying it and getting but not sure what could have been wrong in code.

```
  // Load a glTF resource
  loader.load(
    // resource URL
    "human-small-with-uniform-and-lighting-all.gltf",
    // called when the resource is loaded
    function(gltf) {
      console.log(gltf.animations[0]);
      mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);
      action = mixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[0]);
      action.play();
      scene.add(gltf.scene);
    },
    function(xhr) {
      console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("An error happened");
    }
  );
```

This is json structure of gltf.animations, right side of image

[image]

Comment: You also have to ensure to update the animation mixer in your animation loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quickest way to load a gltf model with the latest version of Three.js on a web page using HTML, CSS and Javascript. The code accesses the model's animation clips, loads the clip in the mixer and updates the mixer in the animation function. An ambient light has been added to the scene as well as orbit controls.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Three.js Examples - Animating 3D GLTF Models | www.shanebrumback.com</title>

</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js@r128/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js@r128/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js@r128/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

    <script type="module">

        // Set up Three js scene
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        {
            const near = 5;
            const far = 10;
            const color = 'black';
            const density = 0.03;
            scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(color, density);
            scene.background = new THREE.Color(color);
        }

        // Set up the camera
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 500);
        camera.position.z = 5;

        // Set up the renderer and configure settings
        let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ReinhardToneMapping;
        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
        renderer.domElement.style.position = 'fixed';
        renderer.domElement.style.zIndex = '-1';
        renderer.domElement.style.left = '0';
        renderer.domElement.style.top = '0';
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // Add camera controls
        const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        controls.dampingFactor = 0.1; // Reduce camera damping for smoother movement
        controls.autoRotate = true; // Make the camera rotate sinuously around the spheres

        // Create the spotlight with shadows
        const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
        spotLight.position.set(10, 20, 30);
        spotLight.castShadow = true;
        scene.add(spotLight);

        // Add ambient light
        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
        scene.add(ambientLight);

        // Create the plane's geometry
        const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100);
        // Create a material to apply to the plane
        const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 'blue',
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            depthWrite: false
        });

        // Create the plane
        const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
        plane.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
        plane.position.y = -3;
        plane.receiveShadow = true;
        plane.castShadow = true
        scene.add(plane);

        //Add a grid helper
        var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 30);
        grid.renderOrder = 0;
        grid.position.y = -3;
        scene.add(grid);

        const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.load('/models/gltf/spinner/scene.gltf', (gltf) => {

            const model = gltf.scene;
            scene.add(model);
            camera.lookAt(scene.position)

            const mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(model);
            const action = mixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[0]);
            action.play();

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                mixer.update(0.01);
                controls.update();
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }

            animate();

        });


        // Resize renderer when window size changes
        window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        });


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```